# ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last) when running a python script from tcl

Tags: python-3.x, tcl

I am running a python script that is called from tcl with the exec command. I have a bunch of modules that are being imported in the py script.
When I run this, I get the error "`ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last)`"
I noticed that it happens only when numpy and paramiko modules are imported. It seems to run just fine without these two leins.

I am not sure what the backend process is when other scripts are called within tcl. Any info is appreciated.

Here is the example of what my file has.

tcl:

```
exec python hello.py
```

hello.py:

```
from pathlib import Path  
#import numpy  
import subprocess  
#import paramiko  
import logging  
import itertools
```

Like I said, it works with the commented out import statements.

Edit: The tcl interpreter is embedded in another software I am using (IPG CarMaker). I am guessing that this may be the issue.

Comment: You perhaps ought to tell us what the traceback says. That almost certainly says outright enough information to tell us what is going wrong, whereas without it we're just completely unable to do anything to advise. (I know that the code won't work for me; I don't have `paramiko` installed.)

Comment: @DonalFellows thank you for the reply. That is another thing that it only outputs "ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last)" and nothing after that. 
It also doesnt work with numpy even without paramiko.

Comment: That's very funny; when I try generating a traceback like that when calling Python from Tcl, I get the whole traceback (multiple lines) in the Tcl error message. The code that is processing the Tcl error message must be throwing away the second (and subsequent) lines of the message. Is this in eggdrop? That's got pretty nasty default error handling that throws away bits of message…